# Is there an SVN / Code repo type service for word docs?

Tags: microsoft-word, svn

I was wondering if there were a service that'll save each revision i make on my word document and allows me to view file differences and changes?

Comment: Check this: http://superuser.com/questions/45006/version-control-support-on-microsoft-word-2007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word has a track changes feature built right in. Do you need something more than this?

Comment: ...and there's also a feature that lets you "diff" two Word documents even if you forgot to turn on "tracking changes".

Comment: @Reuben, when did that feature show up?  only recent versions or available in older ones too?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if you use a Subversion repo for your doc with the TortoiseSVN shell extension, the track changes functionality is used to highlight inter-revision changes when you do a visual diff. Very handy!